# Using getch() in while loop

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

I am writing a program which fills the console with a letter every time it is resized, and when it is resized the letter changes to the next in the alphabet.

I also want to make it so that when the user presses q the program ends. This currently works, however if I do not enter any letter then my printing code is never reached. How do I fix this?

```
while(1){  
  keyInput = getch();
  if(keyInput == 'q' || keyInput == 'Q'){
    break;
  }

  letter++; //Get next letter
  if(letter > 90){
    letter = 65;    //Loop back to A
  }

  //Print updated output
  pause();  //Wait for sigwinch
  clear();  //Clear window
  ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws);
  resizeterm(ws.ws_row, ws.ws_col);

  for(i = 0; i < ws.ws_row; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < ws.ws_col; j++){
      addch(letter);
    }
  }
  refresh();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by  "if I do not enter any letter then my printing code is never reached"

Comment: Pretty simple fix. Draw the screen before you block with `getch`.

Comment: I assume that the code continues to wait for input.
If I press q -- program exits.
If I press nothing and resize window -- nothing happens.
If I press any other key and resize window -- the proper input displays but then pressing 'q' does nothing.

Comment: @Subinoy OP is trying to refer the _blocking_ introduced by call to `getch()`.

Comment: @Bradley Displaying the characters first makes it so that the display is correct, but pressing 'q' does nothing.

Comment: Don't hardcode values, and don't make assumptions about the character set: `if(letter > 'Z') { letter = 'A'; }`

Answer (score 1):

Given the combination of calls, the OP is using ncurses (rather than say, yet another conio question).  Given that (a complete program would help), the chunk beginning `pause()` is meaningless, since ncurses will return `KEY_RESIZE` if one remembers to use

```
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
```

in the initialization section, as well as updating the `LINES` and `COLS` values.  The given section of the program could be rewritten something like this:

```
keypad(stdscr, TRUE); /* allow KEY_RESIZE to be read on SIGWINCH */
timeout(50);          /* wait 50 milliseconds for each character */

while(1){  
  keyInput = getch();
  if (keyInput == ERR) {
    continue;         /* ignore when there was a timeout - no data */
  } else if(keyInput == 'q' || keyInput == 'Q'){
    break;
  } else if (keyInput == KEY_RESIZE) {
      letter++; //Get next letter
      if(letter > 'Z'){
        letter = 'A';    //Loop back to A
      }

      erase();
      move(0,0);
      for(i = 0; i < LINES; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
          addch(letter);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The `timeout` call fixes the blocking-problem alluded to.